# Sathyam and Dharmam

Tags: dharma

I like to hear about scriptural sources that convincingly declare Truth as inner content of Dharma, even if it is commonly known that lying ( including not standing up to one's own words of commitment), evil/adharma go together.

It is known that Truth is non-violence or even Love, and violence is adharma, so logically it is correct. However there may be numerous teachings by sages on the common topic of Truth being *the* active ingredient of Dharma.

My question follows the two Vedic statements

*Ahimsa paramo Dharmaha*

*Sathyam = Non- violence= Ahimsa*

We eliminate the common variable Ahimsa from these two equivalences.

Comment: Your statement -  **Truth is non-violence or even Love, and violence is adharma** - does not fit in the perspective of Dharma.  Unprovoked violence may be adharma, but resorting to retaliation in self defence or to support a Just cause is not violence

Comment: I was referring to violence as *himsa,* meted out  in conditions that can never be justified.

Comment: Please qualify your question so.  Right now, your question is not that explicit @Narasimham

Comment: Thanks. shall try to expand on the question

Comment: Sathyameva Jayathe in any dharmic struggle. The ancient declaration of Truth and Dharma  to me appears identical conceptually.

Comment: Truth is not non-violence, but Aatama(no Tamas) while its opposite Tamas or ignorance and its actions is Adharma. Mahabharata was a violent war invoked by Krishna avatar to destroy Tamsik kings like Duryodhana. Since aatma alone is immortal, its also called Sat/truth,and since everyone contains aatma, hence "Ahimsa paramo dharam", but that does not mean one should not defend while being attacked by lion or any violent person. Greater good should be given the priority.

Comment: Yes, even Gandhiji advocated violence in self defence to counter worst violence.